# Related wallpapers excluding the current wallpaper using php

Tags: php, mysql

I put this code in Related Wallpapers section in my wallpaper website. The below code displays me wallpapers for a specific tag (for ex:abstract,love..) but it displays me the current wallpaper and i would like to make random wallpapers in related wallpapers section. 
How to do this ?

My php code :

```
<?php
//Related wallpaper
$searchtag = $info['tag'];
$related = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM covers WHERE tag='$searchtag' LIMIT 2 ") or       die(mysql_error());
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array($related))
{ 
echo $info['name'];
Echo '<img src="thumb/'.$info['thumbflname'].'"></br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556330/show-mysql-random-result

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM covers WHERE tag='$searchtag' LIMIT 2
```

should be

```
SELECT * FROM covers WHERE tag='$searchtag' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2
```

Comment: But it shouldn't display current wallpaper. Can we do this by using any IF condition or something ?

Comment: @Hasi Haseeb you can add a condition like AND wallpaper_id != CURRENT_WALL_PAPER_ID in where clause

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this

`mysql_query('SELECT * FROM covers WHERE tag="'.$searchtag.'" LIMIT '.rand(1, 55).', 1')`